# URLConnection does not respect ReadTimeout

Tags: java, android

I'm using `URLConnection` in my code. I've set `ReadTimeout` to 5 seconds, but it doesn't come to effect. When I switch the wifi off the IO Exception is being called immidiately.

```
 URLConnection conn;     
 conn = new URL(StringUrls[0]).openConnection();
 conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
 in = conn.getInputStream();


      try {
           len = in.read(buffer);
           bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
           bufOutstream.close();
         } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

IO Exception:

```
12-17 12:41:35.332  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:542)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.read(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:41)
12-17 12:41:35.362  12761-13268/com.app.example W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example code as blow,

it will try max 20 times to read the correct data.

if exception occurs in one time,it just try again after 5 seconds.

```
private static int currentRetryCount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    retryRead(20);
}

public static void retryRead(int maxRetryCount) throws InterruptedException {
    if (currentRetryCount <= maxRetryCount) {
        try {
            System.out.println("try count " + currentRetryCount);
            URLConnection conn;
            conn = new URL("").openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.getInputStream();
            // if nothing happens,it just return
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if exception raises,it will try again after 5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            currentRetryCount++;
            retryRead(maxRetryCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, this not precisely answer my question I decided to accept it because it seems like a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `setConnectTimeout`?

connectTimeout is the timeout for establishing the connection. 
readTimeout is the timeout for reading data from the input stream after the connection has been established.

Also, the reason you get IOException immediately when your Wifi is off is because the connection gets aborted immediately regardless of the timeout if you have no active media for connection.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. I did the mistake only here not in my "real code". I had to simplify it in order to post here.

Comment: It could be that the server you are trying to connect to is cutting the connection and returning a ETIMEDOUT. Try to connect to a non-active IP in your network  and see if the timeout duration is the same...

Answer (score 0):

What effect do you want?Can you show more detail information ?

Set ReadTimeOut To N Seconds ,does not mean total read time will less than N seconds.

It mean's the max time between 2 data packages(By a connection ,you will get a lot of data packages) .

for example ,if there is no data available in N seconds,than the SocketTimeoutException will be raised.

Comment: I want to "hold" the URLconnection while the internet connection is interrupted. So when it reconnects during this 5 seconds buffer reading will be retried.

Comment: I think you can do your recovery in catch block.If the exception occurs,you can sleep the thread for N seconds,then try to reopen the connection.

Comment: Yes, it is a way, but what if the interruption will happen many times? Could you post the example code (may be only a scheme) how you see this?